# <virtualport type='openvswitch'/> is NOT recognized

Tags: libvirt, openvswitch

In order to make my vm use the openvswitch interface I have to add the following lines to a vm xml config file:

```
<source bridge='ovsbr'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
```

I edit the file, anyway while the first line is corrctly saved, the second one is not. 
It simply disappears, so I think the virtualport tag is not recognized...but this leads to an error when I start the virtual machine.

Has the xml specification changed? Or I do something wrong?
Here is the output of

```
virsh --version=long
```

> Virsh command line tool of libvirt 0.9.8
>        See web site at http://libvirt.org/

```
 Compiled with support for:
 Hypervisors: Xen QEmu/KVM UML OpenVZ LXC Test
 Networking: Remote Daemon Network Bridging Nwfilter VirtualPort
 Storage: Dir Disk Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI LVM
 Miscellaneous: AppArmor Secrets Debug Readline
```

Comment: It seems you haven't asked a question :)

Comment: Paste the output of `virsh --version=long`.

Comment: I edited the post...I really don't know where the problem is, it just seems that virtualport tag is not a valid tag for the xml...I tried with different attributes but it is never saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open vSwitch support requires [libvirt 0.9.11 or later](http://git.openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=openvswitch;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL.Libvirt;hb=HEAD). Your libvirt is too old.

To resolve the problem, upgrade your system.